# Hibernate 5 Multitenancy DATABASE appraoch : Face issue to close hikari connection pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, multi-tenant

In My Application Have 4 database server and each database server have 9 schema , so i use hibernate multitenancy for the session and its working ,
but i face one problem , its not close hikari connection pool object
for example in my development code every time code auto build its create new connection pool like HikariPool-5 - Start completed , its not close last 4 hikari pool when application stop or restart

```
public class DataSourceMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, DataSource> dataSourcesNSAP;

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        return this.dataSourcesNSAP.values().iterator().next();
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        return this.dataSourcesNSAP.get(tenantIdentifier);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("-----------releaseAnyConnection methode called-----------");
        connection.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("-----------releaseConnection methode called-----------");
        releaseAnyConnection(this.dataSourcesNSAP.get(tenantIdentifier).getConnection());
        
    }
    
     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
         return ConnectionProvider.class.equals( unwrapType ) ||
                    MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class.equals( unwrapType ) ||
                    AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider.class.isAssignableFrom( unwrapType );
        }
        @Override
        public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
             if ( isUnwrappableAs( unwrapType ) ) {
                    return (T) this;
                }
                throw new UnknownUnwrapTypeException( unwrapType );
        }
        @Override
        public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
            return true;
        }
        
        
        
} 

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MultiTenantHibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataBaseProperty dbproperty;
@Bean(name = "dataSourcesNSAP")
    public Map<String, DataSource> getAllDataSources() {
        Map<String, DataSource> result = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, DbProperty> dpMap = dbproperty.getDb();
        DataSource ds ;
        DataSourceBuilder<?> db_builder ;
        for (Map.Entry<String, DbProperty> entry : dpMap.entrySet()) {
            db_builder = DataSourceBuilder
                        .create().driverClassName(dbproperty.getDriver())
                        .username(entry.getValue().getUsername())
                        .password(entry.getValue().getPassword())
                        .url(entry.getValue().getUrl());
            ds = db_builder.build();
            result.put(entry.getKey(), ds);
        }

        return result;
    }   
    

    @Bean
    public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {

        return new DataSourceMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
        return new TenantDBIdentifierResolverImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public PhysicalNamingStrategy getPhysicalNamingRegistry() {
        return new CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setMultiTenantConnectionProvider(multiTenantConnectionProvider());
        sessionFactory.setCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver(currentTenantIdentifierResolver());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "nic.in.nsap.model" });
        //sessionFactory.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(getPhysicalNamingRegistry());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.multiTenancy", "DATABASE");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

> // Finally i get the session object like
> sessionfactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("USER1").openSession();

please someone resolve my issue and also suggest for me if any better other way for fulfill my requirement

Comment: Please someone see my issue

Comment: you say that the last 5 connections are not closed, where are you accessing your DAO, show us if you are using a JPARepository with / without EntityManager

Comment: In local for every build, the IDE will restart and will recycle your connections, can you please elaborate your question